# removing empty lines from txt file

Tags: java

I manage to get this code working. It reads test.txt with about 10000 words (each word in its own line) and formats them first Alphabeticly and second BY length. However when i open sort.txt i get first like a lot of empty lines after that the words are properly formated. My question is how to remove thos empty lines since they cant be there. Will .trim work?

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class sort {
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {  
      if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
         return 1;
      } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
         return -1;
      }
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputFile = "test.txt";
    String outputFile = "sort.txt";

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
    fileReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lineList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }   

    Collections.sort(lineList, new MyComparator());

    FileWriter Fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }       
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileWriter.close();

}
}
```

Comment: just two minor points: there is no need to call flush() before close(). You also don't need to close the fileWriter, since it will be closed when you close the printWriter.

Comment: thanks really new to programming still

Answer (score 1):

just dont add those empty lines:

```
while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!inputLine.isEmpty()) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` also has `.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
for (String outputLine : lineList) {
    if (!"".equals(outputLine.trim()))
        out.println(outputLine);
    //...
```

You can't use `.trim()` on its own to solve the problem because it just hacks off whitespace at the beginning and end. It'll leave an empty `String` unchanged. I've used it here to make sure that you also omit lines that aren't empty but do have just whitespace in.

Comment: @RokIvartnik You're outputting in two places, so you'd need it twice. But Terry's suggestion of doing the same at input time is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it when you are actually adding string to list that would be good approach like

```
while (!StringUtils.isEmpty(inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine())) {
```

Comment: the problem seem to be in aplhabetical comparison not length

Answer (score 0):

Manage to make it work. Here is the solution. Thanks for all yours replies.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class sort {
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {  
      if (o1.trim().length() > o2.trim().length()) {
         return 1;
      } else if (o1.trim().length() < o2.trim().length()) {
         return -1;
      }
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputFile = "test.txt";
    String outputFile = "sort.txt";

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }

    Collections.sort(lineList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Collections.sort(lineList, new MyComparator()); 

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    FileWriter Fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Fw);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        if (!"".equals(outputLine.trim()))
            out.println(outputLine);        }       
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileWriter.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is working as expected? Based on the trim in your `MyComparator` I believe you deal also with leading/trailing blanks. Create a test.txt with following 6 lines (the dot should be replaced by a blank) `.aa`, `.bbb`, `aaa`, `cc.`, `cc..`, `ddd`.

Comment: Hello, i know if i leave space in from or behind a word it doesnt use it. Wasnt really important to me since i am not dealing with that. However if you know how to solve this please respond so i can learn even more.

Comment: If the lines do not have leading/trailing blank characters. Then you can ommit the the sort for length. Maybe it's better you edit your question an provide a example of your input (can be a genrice one, without your real data) and the expected output. To get a better understanding what you want to solve.